# Enable and select values of Drop-down based on the value selected in another Drop-down

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I have couple of Drop-downs on a page; after selecting a value on the First Drop-down, Second Drop-down will get enable and the values get loaded accordingly.

When running manually, after selecting a value in First Drop-down, the page gets loaded and the Second Drop-down gets enabled and the values are listed according to the value selected in First Drop-down.

However, when do automation using Selenium Webdriver (in Java), only the value of First Drop-down gets selected and the Second Drop-down is never enabled or loaded with the values.

Even tried with WebDriverWait as below, but still no luck.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("event")));
```

Noticed that only we move out the page (ALT+TAB)and come again to the page the page is getting loaded and the Second Drop-down is enabled.

Below exception is also thrown,

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: event
```

Please advise.

**Coding with Page Object Model:**

*In POM Class:*

```
//Create Object for Page 1
CreateAsset asset = PageFactory.initElements(wd,CreateAsset.class);


//Read the values of First & Second Drop-down from an excel

String list_event_type = readsheet.getRow(1).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
String list_event = readsheet.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

//Calling Drop-down methods in Page Factory POM Class 
asset.selectEventType(list_event_type);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 50);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("event")));
asset.selectEvent(list_event);
```

*In Page Factory Class:*

```
//select the given value on the First Drop-down

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "eventType")
public WebElement   eventType;

public void selectEventType(String eventType)
{
    this.eventType.sendKeys(eventType);
}

//select the given value on Sescond Drop-down

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "event")
public WebElement   event;

public void selectEvent(String event)
{
    this.event.sendKeys(event);
}
```

Comment: please,share the code related to selection of first dropdown

Comment: post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same page object to select both values, the problem is that the page object only initializes one (at the very start. This means that the event property never gets initialized with values when the eventType element is changed.

Two options:
1. Re-init the page object after selecting the eventType

```
//Calling Drop-down methods in Page Factory POM Class 
asset.selectEventType(list_event_type);
asset = PageFactory.initElements(wd,CreateAsset.class);
```

2. Change selectEventType to return a new page object, essentially this does the same thing as above

   public CreateAsset selectEventType(String eventType)
   {
       this.eventType.sendKeys(eventType);
       return new CreateAsset(_driver);
   }

Then you would call this in your POM with

```
asset = asset.selectEventType(list_event_type);
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that to format correctly, sorry. Hope it helps

Comment: Steve,

Thank you for your reply! Still am getting the exception when I tried with option 1.

However, I’ve just successfully selected the Second Drop-down by automating the manual workaround of pressing ALT+TAB.

wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.TAB));

Comment: Ah, i see. Your method of selecting the first dropdown wasn't triggering the JS to populate the second!

Answer (score 0):

Below workaround works well as expected!

```
wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.TAB));
```